# Como ler JSON com lua?

Tags: lua

Gostaria de saber como ler esse `JSON` abaixo através da linguagem `Lua`.

```
json = '{"nome" : "Wallace de Souza"}'
```

Comment: Você quer saber como interpretar isto ou ler o arquivo? Já viu isto? http://lua-users.org/wiki/JsonModules

Comment: Interpretar. Ler o arquivo é outra pergunta ;)

Comment: Estou vendo agora ;)

Answer (score 1):

Esse link é para uma lib em lua Puro [http://regex.info/code/JSON.lua] para fazer o encode/decode de JSON, já usei em produção e funciona extremamente bem, além disso o código está comentado e é bem simples de entender, recomendo o uso, para "instalar" basta salvar o arquivo na pasta do seu projeto e usar o 'require' normalmente.

Comment: Amei essa lib !